# CircularProgressIndicator not showing when a button pressed

Tags: flutter, async-await, flutter-getx, flutter-circularprogressindicator

I'm trying to implement a button that when the user press the button the user will login throw firebase and the button should show Circular Progress Indicator while firebase logging complete.
for some reason the Progress Indicator now showing.

I tried to replace

```
await SignUpController.instance.registerUser(number);
```

with

```
await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2));
```

and that shows the Circular Progress Indicator.

```
Rx<bool> isLoading = false.obs;
///...
SizedBox(
                   height: 40,
                   width: double.infinity,
                   child: ElevatedButton(
                       onPressed: () async {
                         isLoading.value = true;
                         await SignUpController.instance.registerUser(number);
                         isLoading.value = false;
                       },
                       child: Obx(
                         () => !isLoading.value
                             ? Text(
                                 "Continue",
                                 style: TextStyle(
                                     fontSize: 20,
                                     fontWeight: FontWeight.normal),
                               )
                             : CircularProgressIndicator(),
                       ))),
```

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that the call to `SignUpController.instance.registerUser` is happening so fast that you do not see the state being changed. Or there could be something wrong with your `registerUser` method.

Comment: Future<void> registerUser(PhoneNumber phoneNumber) async {
    await AuthenticationRepository.instance.registerUser(phoneNumber);
  }  Future<void> registerUser(PhoneNumber phoneNumber) async {
    this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    await _auth.verifyPhoneNumber(
      timeout: const Duration(seconds: 60),
      phoneNumber: phoneNumber.phoneNumber!,
      verificationCompleted: _verificationCompleted,
      verificationFailed: _verificationFailed,
      codeSent: _codeSent,
      codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: _codeAutoRetrievalTimeout,
    );
  }

Comment: here is my code for registerUser if u can help plz

Comment: When you call the `registerUser` function, are you getting the verification code to the entered phone number? Just asking to make sure if the function is indeed working properly

Comment: no im just sending a request to firebase to send the user code. if every think ok in firebase the OTP code will be send to user

Comment: Yes. I understand that. I see that in your original code's `onPressed` function, you're calling the `registerUser` function. I'm just asking if you're receiving the OTP when you call the function. If you failed to configure Firebase properly, the function might be failing which could make the Future resolve instantly, and that's why you're not seeing the loading indicator.

Comment: oh yes yes im geting OTP after a while from firebase, every think work fine for firebase.

Comment: Alright. You should try adding an artificial delay inside your `registerUser` function (i.e `Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 5))` and see if the progress indicator appears.

Comment: i did that see my post. and that shows the indicator.

Comment: I'm so thankful for u, that right the registerUser so fast.

Comment: I meant add the delay *inside* the `registerUser` function, not replace it in the `onPressed` callback

Answer (score 0):

```
Center(
        child: Container(
          height: 40,
          color: Colors.black54,
          width: double.infinity,
          child: InkWell(
              onTap: () async {
                isLoading.toggle();
              },
              child:StreamBuilder(
                stream: isLoading.stream,
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  return isLoading.value == true
                      ? const Center(
                        child: Text(
                    "Continue",
                    style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 20,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.normal),
                  ),
                      )
                      : const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                }
              ),
          )),
      ),
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).